# Getting Dates value from Input to mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't seem to get the data from the database if im trying to get the data from Variable of $Fromdatepicker or $Todatepicker but if i put the dates like this '10/17/2019' in mySQL it works perfectly fine and shows the data

i looked up how the dates are being shown from $Fromdatepicker or $Todatepicker and they are in excat format of what i need 10/17/2019' but still the data will not show if i am using them

i am getting the value from html to php using Ajax and its showing if i echo them but not when i am trying to use them in mySQL

```
$DailyConfirmedsql = "SELECT general.RR,Status_Type,Confirmation_Date FROM general LEFT JOIN statupdate ON general.RR = statupdate.RR LEFT JOIN shipmentdates ON general.RR = shipmentdates.RR WHERE statupdate.Status_Type = 'Confirmed' AND shipmentdates.Confirmation_Date BETWEEN '$Fromdatepicker' AND '$Todatepicker'";
```

this is to get the count of "confirmed" in the database

```
$DailyConfirmedStatus = $conn->query($DailyConfirmedsql);
$numberDailyConfirmed = mysqli_num_rows($DailyConfirmedStatus);
```

if i used the '$Fromdatepicker' AND '$Todatepicker' the result would be 0
but if i wrote the dates into the mySQL script like '10/17/2019' AND '10/30/2019' i would get a result of 17 which is the correct

Comment: If you output the $DailyConfirmedsql and run it manually on your database. What result do you get? Provide us with both the sql you used and the result

Comment: Just edited with the result and how i get the count

Comment: I meant to check the actual query build through php. if you do a ```echo ($DailyConfirmedsql); and use that output to run it manually in mysql it could give you a better insight. I think something is off in the query which faults the running in sql. You just need to figure out what is actually passed to mysql to be able to make the right adjustments to the script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$from = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.Y', $Fromdatepicker)->format('Y-m-d');
$to = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.Y', $Todatepicker)->format('Y-m-d');
$DailyConfirmedsql = "SELECT general.RR,Status_Type,Confirmation_Date FROM general LEFT JOIN statupdate ON general.RR = statupdate.RR LEFT JOIN shipmentdates ON general.RR = shipmentdates.RR WHERE statupdate.Status_Type = 'Confirmed' AND shipmentdates.Confirmation_Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
```